# Service don't return data from json by using BehaviorSubject

Tags: html, angular, behaviorsubject

I have a JSON data as below:

```
import { Person } from './models';

export const People = [
  {
    name: 'Kimberly',
    lastname: 'Garcia',
    age: 26,
    sex: 'F',
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris',
    lastname: 'Williams',
    age: 64,
    sex: 'M',
  },
] as Person[];
```

I have a service which who emit data during ngOnInit hook like below:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { People } from "./data.json";
import { Person } from "./models";

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  people$: Observable<Person[]>;
  private _people$: BehaviorSubject<Person[]>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setPeople();
  }

  getPeople() {
    //Get People list as observable. Please use BehaviorSubject for that.
    this.people$ = this._people$.asObservable();
  }

  setPeople() {
    this._people$.next(People);
  }
}
```

I am reading data into the component observable:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AppService } from "./app.service";
import { Person } from "./models";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "interview";
  people$: Observable<Person[]>;

  constructor(private service: AppService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.people$ = this.service.people$;
  }
}
```

I'm presenting data in the template:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let person of people$ | async">
    {{ person.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't get it why I cannot see any data from JSON. I'm adding them to the BehaviorSubject in ngOnInit hook. What's wrong? I also don't see any bugs in console of browser. I couldn't find solution - I have to use BehaviorSubject.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating `_people$` to create an instance of a BehaviorSubject using `new`:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { People } from "./data.json";
import { Person } from "./models";

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  // initialize with empty array for ngFor safety
  private _people$: BehaviorSubject<Person[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Person[]>([]);
  // this can still be in getPeople if you prefer
  people$: Observable<Person[]> = this._people$.asObservable();

  constructor() {
     this.setPeople();
  }

  setPeople() {
    this._people$.next(People);
  }
}
```

A couple other issues in your component when you set `this.people$`, the value of `this.service.people$` is effectively undefined/null because `getPeople()` has not been called first. You can avoid that by updating `getPeople()` to return the actual observable `people$` of the service, or simply setting `people$` right after you instantiate the behavior subject like `people$: Observable<Person[]> = this._people$.asObservable();`.

Comment: @RobertDaraż So you move setPeople to constructor instead of ngOnInit? Also did you move `people$: Observable<Person[]> = this._people$.asObservable()` out of `getPeople`? How you have it currently, you are assigning the components `this.people$` a value of undefined as `getPeople()` is not called first. That can be avoided by simply just setting `people$` in the service without getPeople().

Comment: Perfect! It's working but please explain why it didn't work with ngOnInit life hook? Please explain with the details.

Comment: `getPeople` was never called based on your code, so the service's `this.people$ = this._people$.asObservable();` was never executed. Given service class property `people$: Observable<Person[]>` was not initialized, it remained `null/undefined`. So in your component's ngOnInit, `this.people$ = this.service.people$;`, was basically doing `this.people$ = undefined;`

Comment: I changed only one thing: I have added setPeople() method in the constructor of service and that's enough and I can be sure that it'll working properly whole time? Or should I delete getPeople() and should I add `people$: Observable<Person[]> = this._people$.asObservable();` into the service and after that in the component `this.people$ = this.service.people$;`? Which solution is better 1 or 2?

Comment: Make sure to also `new BehaviorSubject<Person[]>([])`. That being said, I find it easier to have just a single observable at the class level rather than a method that creates a new observable. Having a single constant observable can help keep things consistent. You can see an example of how it looks with multiple observables with behavior subject: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-behaviorsubject-simpleexample-tr4fic?file=index.ts